# Extract a string from a multiline string

Tags: vba, excel

VBA read the below from a text and assigns it into a variable. I need to extract the Name (in this example, it would be "Canada, Ontraio") from it. But the text will contain more than one occurrences of this "Name" and I should be able to assign each name into an array to re-call it later.

```
ID         = abc123    NAME       = Canada, Ontario                      
NT         = U         SIZE       =      0       BYTES                             
DT ID      = 5A        DEP        =  D E
```

below is the code to read it from the text file:

```
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\\users\test.txt")
txtpro = oFS.ReadAll

If InStr(strarray(intCount), "TYPE") Then
  UserName() = Split(strarray(intCount), "TYPE")
End If

If Not (Not UserName()) Then
    For TotUName = LBound(UserName()) To UBound(UserName())
       Debug.Print UserName(TotUName)
    Next
End if
```

Comment: I won't write the code for you but definitely guide you. let's say we have a string `MyString = "a=b=c=d"` So how do i get `d`? Simple. `MyAr = Split(MyString,"=")` and then `debug.print MyAr (Ubound (MyAr))`

Comment: I tried splitting it exactly as you said, but the problem with that is it assigns everything after the "=". That disputes my purpose of acquiring ONLY the name. How would I take just the name only.

Comment: It will get you anything which is after the LAST "=". Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Oh Ok I know what you mean. Add an If statement. `If instr(1,MyAr (Ubound (MyAr)-1)," NAME ") then debug.print MyAr (Ubound (MyAr))`

Comment: If InStr(strarray(intCount), "TYPE") Then
      UserName() = Split(strarray(intCount), "TYPE")
    End If

Comment: See the answer that i posted. You may have to refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you know how to loop through lines in a file.

Try this

```
'~~> Sample String
s = "ID         = abc123    NAME       = Canada, Ontario"
MyAr = Split(s, "=")

'~~> Check if you have " NAME " in MyAr(UBound(MyAr) - 1)
If InStr(1, MyAr(UBound(MyAr) - 1), " NAME ", vbTextCompare) Then
    Debug.Print MyAr(UBound(MyAr))
End If
```

The above will give you `Canada, Ontario`. The below will give you nothing

```
s = "NT         = U         SIZE       =      0       BYTES     "
MyAr = Split(s, "=")

If InStr(1, MyAr(UBound(MyAr) - 1), " NAME ", vbTextCompare) Then
    Debug.Print MyAr(UBound(MyAr))
End If
```

Comment: I kind of did the same thing that you've suggested, but taking the word "TYPE". Original Coding is amended . Anyhow it is working now and thank you so much Siddhath.